# AES/PKCS5/SHSA256

Tags: python, encryption

I make encryption and decryption using AES/PKCS5/CBC in Python
as I know Java has option AES/CBC/PKCS5.
Python need to make program work as PKCS5.
PKCS5 is an 8 byte block, but when I print `AES.block_size` in Python, it is printed as 16 byte block.
According to definition of PKCS5, I tried:

```py
text = text + (8 - len(text) % 8) * chr(8 - len(text) % 8)
```

When I encrypt that text, an error message shows input must be multiple of 16 length.
When I change `AES.block_size` to 8, all the code works well.
However, I think changing 8 to `AES.block_size` not fit to definition of PKCS5.

Please help me understand.

Comment: Maybe show us some code and expected input/output?

Comment: PKCS5 (for 8-byte block sizes) is actually a wrong term in the context of AES (16 bytes block size) and is used in some languages rather for historical reasons. The correct term is PKCS7 (for larger block sizes e.g. 16 bytes), see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044) for more details.

Comment: you mean I can't use right PKCS5 with AES?

Comment: No. What I am trying to say is that AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in Java actually means PKCS7Padding and uses the term PKCS5Padding only for historical reasons. So you should pad to a block size of 16 bytes in the context of AES. Please read the linked answer, it is very well explained there. Apart from that padding is supported implicitly or explicitly by most libraries (PyCryptodome, Cryptography). A user-defined implementation is usually not necessary.

Comment: omg I totally understand! thank you so much!!!!!!!!! I was really confused but thanks to you, I got it!! thx so so so much!!!! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Create a paddding function

```
def pad(text):
    pad= AES.block_size - (len(text) % AES.block_size))
    assert(pad >= 1 && pad <= AES.block_size)
    return text + chr(pad)*pad
```

and apply the encryption to `pad(text)` instead.

There are historical reasons why some block sizes correspond to the name PKCS5 and others to PKCS7 or even PKCS8. The padding scheme is the same. One is historically tied to DES (before AES even existed) and all block ciphers in the then current standards (PKCS *is* such a standard) had 8 byte blocks.

Just use the above for AES and the correct one for AES in Java and you'll be OK in principle.

Comment: I focused too much on 8 byte. I totally understood thx!!